# C++ Program crashes after asking for the size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I'm trying to write a program with which you can control the data in that array.
But for some reason every time I'm trying to use `arr.size();` the program just crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        int choice;

        cout << "Make new Array with custom size...(1)" << endl;
        cout << "Add amount at the end.............(2)" << endl;
        cout << "Delete amount at the end..........(3)" << endl;
        cout << "Add amount at location i..........(4)" << endl;
        cout << "Delete amount at location i.......(5)" << endl;
        cout << "Delete Array......................(6)" << endl;
        cout << "Show Array........................(7)" << endl;
        cout << "END...............................(0)" << endl;
        cout << "Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        vector<double> arr;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1: {
            int i;

            cout << "Enter array size: ";
            cin >> i;

            arr.resize(i);

            cout << "Set array size to " << i << "!" << endl;
            cout << "Success!" << endl;

            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            double amount;

            cout << "Enter amount: ";
            cin >> amount;

            int location = arr.size();
            cout << location << " " << amount << endl;

            arr[location] = amount;

            cout << arr[location] << endl;
            cout << "Successfully saved!" << endl;

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        }

        case 3:

            arr[arr.size()] = 0;

            cout << "Success: " << arr[arr.size] << endl;

            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            break;

        case 4: {
            int ite;
            float numb;

            cout << "Please enter amount: ";
            cin >> numb;
            cout << "Please enter amount for the i'th location: ";
            cin >> ite;

            cout << "Success!" << endl;

            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            break;
        }

        case 5:
            int ites;

            cout << "Please enter amount for the i'th location: ";
            cin >> ites;

            arr[ites] = 0;

            cout << "Success!" << endl;

            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            break;

        case 6:
            int o;

            for (o = 0; o < arr.size(); o++) {
                arr[o] = 0;
            }

            cout << "Success!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            break;

        case 7:
            int j;

            for (j = 0; j < ARRAYSIZE(arr); j++) {
                cout << "Array[" << j << "] = " << arr[j] << endl;
            }

            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            break;

        case 0: {
            cout << "Exit Program....";

            return 0;
        }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add debugging code, e.g., the array output before calling array.size() ... then you should find your problem. Also you can try a tiny fixed size array with predefinded values and see what happens.

Comment: `arr[arr.size()] = 0;` invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here on this line

```
for(j = 0; j < ARRAYSIZE(arr); j++){
```

What is `ARRAYSIZE`? It's not defined anywhere in your code. You probably meant this instead:

```
for(j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++){
```

Also, note how `size` is a function, so you need to call it by putting `()` at the end. This here won't work:

```
cout << "Success: " << arr[arr.size] << endl;
```

You need `arr.size()` to make it compile, and even then, that would be out of bounds. To print the last element, do `arr[arr.size()-1]`, or better yet, `arr.back()` (and make sure that the array isn't empty either way, using `arr.empty()`). To just print the size of the array, do:

```
cout << "Success: " << arr.size() << endl;
```

---

A little side note (don't worry, it didn't cause any problems): in this loop

```
int o;
    for(o = 0; o < arr.size(); o++){
        arr[o] = 0;
    }
```

Since you're not using `o` outside of the loop, you can just move the declaration  into the loop initialization, like this:

```
for(int o = 0; o < arr.size(); o++){
    arr[o] = 0;
}
```

And if you're getting a warning about signed/unsigned mismatch here, you can get rid of it by changing `int` to `unsigned int`.

Comment: Note: `arr[ arr.size()-1 ]` is a recipe for disaster, so don't cookie-cutter it. Like `arr.back()`, it invokes undefined behavior if invoked on an *empty* vector. When using either, make sure the code accounts for a guaranteed-non-empty state either by algorithm or checking `!arr.empty()` prior to use.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean, that I can't use the int o in the loop? (Unsigned)

Comment: Nah, you can use it all the same, like `for(unsigned int o = 0; o < arr.size(); o++){`. The reason why the compiler complains is because `arr.size()` is also an unsigned type, so logically it would make sense to compare unsigned with unsigned types. It might be able to to optimize the code a bit better this way and it prevents errors in some rare cases (for instance if your vector has 3 billion elements, which would be out of range for an `int`, but not for `unsigned int`).

Answer (score 1):

On line no 83 (inside case 3)

You forgot the parenthesis

You have written

```
cout << "Success: " << arr[arr.size] << endl;
```

If you want to call the function size() which will return the size, it should be :

```
cout << "Success: " << arr[arr.size()] << endl;
```

Comment: Your fix still invokes undefined behavior. A non-empty vector can only be indexed with values in [0..(arr.size()-1)].

Comment: fixed it but it still doesn't change anything

Comment: ` case 3:

        arr[arr.size()] = 0;

      cout << "Success: " << arr[arr.size()] << endl;



       system("pause");
       system("cls");
`

Comment: as suggested by @WhozCraig 
Please consider bounds of the vector (0 to size-1)
Almost every where, you have upper bound same as size of arr